# Laravel 4 search function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

From my previous question, I've gotten this code from a user.

```
    // app/routes.php
Route::get('characters', 'CharactersController@all');
Route::get('characters/{name}', 'CharactersController@detail');


// app/controllers/CharactersController.php
class CharactersController extends BaseController
{
    public function all()
    {
        // show all characters
    }

    public function detail($name)
    {
        // find character by name & show detail for example
        return View::make('acc.test');
    }
}

// app/views/acc/test.blade.php
// HTML::style('css/style.css') loads CSS file located at public/css/style.css
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

also, the search function:

```
<form action="{{ URL::action('CharactersController@search') }}" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search-term">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

```
    public function search()
{
    $name = Input::get('search-term');
    $searchResult = Character::where('name', '=', $name)->get();
    ....
}

Route::get('characters/search', 'CharactersController@search');
```

how could I in the :

```
public function detail($name) { // find character by name & show detail for example return View::make('acc.test'); }
```

how could I find the character by name? I've tried doing something like

```
$name = $player->name
```

(I have a model called players, I've also changed Character::where to Player::where), what do I have to insert there? also, how could I display it in the view?

So I mean when I search a player by name it displays the players name ($player->name) for every specific player.

Also do I have to change the relations in the model toHasMany or something like that?

Comment: What is your specific question? I can read a lot of question but I cannot determine what actually is the real question. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
public function detail($name) {
    $player = Player::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
}
```

If more players can have same name I would rather pass ID instead of name, so in this case use this solution

```
public function detail($id) {
    $player = Player::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, do I need to return it to a view? Something like:
`return View::make('blabla')->with('player', $player);` , and then what am I going to do in blabla.blade.php? Also, it works with the search function right?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to achieve. Do you want to load player from DB and show details to user? Then yes, you should...

Comment: Yes, I want to load player from database and show details to the user. Also, it works with the search function? What should I write in my view? Should I do something like a foreach statement or? could you give me an example, just like displaying players name..